# From List<string> to Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net

I have List

```
List<string> listOfAtt = new List<string>();
```

where `listOfAtt[0] = "FirsName"`, `listOfAtt[1] = "Homer"` etc.

How can I create a `Dictionary<srting,string>` of this kind

`listOfAtt["FirsName"] = "Homer"`???

Comment: So the first two values are a key value pair, then the next two, the next two, yadda yadda...?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: What is the use case here? Are the values in the list unique? The below answers all do not take duplicates into account and will all fail if e.g. "FirsName" is twice in the list at an even index.

Comment: The values that should be keys are unique, so those answers I accept=)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `listOfAtt.Count` is even and items at even indices are unique you can do below.

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfAtt.Count; i+=2) {
    dic.Add(listOfAtt[i], listOfAtt[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: You made a typo twice, srting instead of string ;)

Comment: copy and pasted the question I bet ;)

Comment: @judgeja probably ^^ I read too fast, i didn't saw it in the question :P

Answer (score 7):

Assuming uniqueness of keys, a LINQ-y way to do it would be:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, listOfAtt.Count / 2)
          .ToDictionary(x => listOfAtt[2 * x], x => listOfAtt[2 * x + 1]);
```

If things are not so unique, you could extend this logic, group by key and return a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` like:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, listOfAtt.Count / 2)
          .Select(i => new { Key = listOfAtt[2 * i], Value = listOfAtt[2*i+1] })
          .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(X => X.Value).ToList());
```

Comment: Nice use of `Enumerable.Range`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'll probably use loop)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is probably using a for loop

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfAtt.Count; i+=2){
    dict.Add(listOfAtt[i], listOfAtt[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: `new Dictionary<string,string>` should be `new Dictionary<string,string>();`, `listOfAtt.count` should be `listOfAtt.Count`, and `dict.add` should be `dict.Add`.

Comment: @Bacon Correct :) I use vb.net primarily so I usually don't worry much about case-sensitivitiy or parentheseis